# How to optimize a clinical scoring algorithm?

Tags: regression, optimization, clinical-trials

I've made two studies on clinical data that correlates with a disease. The clinical data can be aggregated into a score, such that the higher the score the higher your % of having the disease.

However, I'd like to optimize this data to figure out if one clinical symptom may be more important than another and should receive more points.

What would be the best way of doing this?

The data is continuous (measurements), discrete (categorical) and binary for different types of symptoms and radiologic findings in patients.

Comment: Have you given thought to what "more important" means in your use case? Once you define that, it might be more obvious how to do the optimization.

Comment: Which variables will increase the diagnostic accuracy of the algorithm by tweaking them. Say 2 points for this variable instead of 1 point.

Answer (score 0):

"Importance" is poorly defined here, as is "optimization". Most disease risk models have very simple formulations, because clinicians want to understand the inputs and maintain veto power over the algorithms. For instance, BMI 20-25 is a less good marker of cardiovascular fitness in muscular men and women. Additionally, a feature can be best predicted by a highly complex expression and it can be unclear how the various terms should be used - for instance, smoking and alcohol use are commonly best fit with quadratic terms, but these problematically have local minima in the range of observed quantities, implying a very small domain where "it's worse for you to do the healthy thing" - and the science spins out of control. Little wonder the Framingham model coursely considers smoking status as 3 levels "never / prior / current" when pack-years of smoking is a *strong* (but difficult to accurately collect) predictor of cardiovascular disease.

An exploratory approach that many analysts use is the plain logistic regression model. Scale all inputs regardless of distribution according to normal(0,1) distributions so that the effect sizes are unitless. Fit the logistic regression model, pick variables with the largest odds ratios as important features. A more sophisticated approach is to fit a LASSO GLM considering different L1 penalties and depict the "entrance" pattern of covariates to lesser and lesser penalized models.